# Java expression parsing with ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, expression, antlr

I'm writing a toolkit in Java that uses Java expression parsing.  I thought I'd try using ANTLR since

1. It seems to be used ubiquitously for this sort of thing
2. There don't seem to be a lot of open source alternatives
3. I actually tried to write my own generalized parser a while back and gave up.  That stuff's hard.

I have to say, after what I feel is a lot of reading and trying different things (more than I had expected to spend, anyway), ANTLR seems incredibly difficult to use.  The API is very unintuitive--I'm never quite sure whether I'm calling it right.

Although ANTLR tutorials and examples abound, I haven't had luck finding any examples that involve parsing Java "expressions" -- everyone else seems to want to parse whole java files.

I started off calling it like this:

```
        Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(text));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
        ParseTree result = parser.expression();
```

but that wouldn't parse the whole expression.  E.g. with text "a.b" it would return a result that only consisted of the "a" part, just quitting after the first thing it could parse.

Fine.  So I changed to:

```
        String input = "return " + text + ";";
        Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(input));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
        ParseTree result = parser.returnStatement();
        result = result.getChild(1);
```

thinking this would force it to parse the entire expression, then I could just extract the part I cared about.  That worked for name expressions like "a.b", but if I try to parse a method expression like "a.b.c(d)" it gives an error:

```
line 1:12 mismatched input '(' expecting '.'
```

Interestingly, `a()`, `a.b()`, and `a.b.c` parse fine, but `a.b.c()` also dies with the same error.

Is there an ANTLR expert here who might have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Separately, it bothers me quite a bit that the error above is printed to stderr, but I can't find it in the result object anywhere.  I'd like to be able to present that error message (vague as it is) to the user that entered the expression--they may not be looking at a console, and even if they are, there's no context there.  Is there a way to find that information in the result I get back?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a rule like `expression`, ANTLR will stop parsing once it recognizes an expression.

You can force it to continue by adding an `EOF to you start rule.

(You don’t want to modify the actual `expressions rule, but you can add a rule like this:

```
expressionStart: expressions EOF;
```

Then you can use:

```
ParseTree result = parser.expressionStart();
```

This will force ANTLR to continue parsing you’re input until it reaches the end of you input.

---

re: returnStatement

When i run `return a.b.c();` through the ANTLR Preview in IntelliJ, I get this parse tree:

[image]

A little bit of following the grammar rules, and I stumble across these rules:

```
typeName: Identifier | packageOrTypeName '.' Identifier;

packageOrTypeName
    : Identifier
    | packageOrTypeName '.' Identifier
    ;
```

That both rules include an alternative for `packageOrTypeName '.' Identifier` looks problematic to me.

In the tree, we see `primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary:2` which indicates a match of the second alternative in this rule:

```
primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary
    : literal
    | typeName ('[' ']')* '.' 'class' // <-- trying to match this rule
    | unannPrimitiveType ('[' ']')* '.' 'class'
    | 'void' '.' 'class'
    | 'this'
    | typeName '.' 'this'
    | '(' expression ')'
    | classInstanceCreationExpression_lfno_primary
    | fieldAccess_lfno_primary
    | arrayAccess_lfno_primary
    | methodInvocation_lfno_primary
    | methodReference_lfno_primary
    ;
```

I'm out of time at the moment, but will keep looking at it.  It seems pretty unlikely there's this obvious a bug in the Java8Parser.g4, but it certainly seems like a bug at the moment.  I'm not sure what about the context would change how this is parsed (by context, meaning where `returnStatement` is natively called in the grammar.)

I tried this input (starting with the `compilationUnit` rule:

```
class Test {
    class A {
       public B  b;
    }
    class B {
        String c() {
            return "";
        }
    }
    String test() {
        A a = new A();
        return a.b.c();
    }
}
```

And it parses correctly (so, we've not found a major bug in the Java8Parser grammar ):

[image]

Still, this doesn't seem right.

Getting closer:

If I start with the `block` rule, and wrap in curly braces (`{return a.b.c();}`), it parses fine.

I'm going to go with the theory that ANTLR needs a bit more lookahead to resolve an "ambiguity".

Comment: That's wonderful, thanks! Definitely seems to have gotten me past that. 

Do you know why the returnStatement() method didn't work though?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious about the `returnStatement`.  I'll have to find a few minutes to pull things down and run a test.

Comment: I've added (quite a lot) of what I'm seeing looking into `returnStatement`, but it's something of a puzzle at the moment.  Does the same thing result in a valid parse tree if used in a larger context??  (I just tried starting at the `statement` rule, and get the same "problem"

Comment: Wow, thanks for checking that out.  Didn't expect you to spend that much time on it--just wondered if you knew off the top of your head.  Your original answer fixed my problem.  I assume it must work in a larger context, as well used as this grammar is.  Like you, I assume it can't be a bug we've exposed with input so simple.