# ANTLR Java 8, odd behavior parsing with `returnStatement` as start rule,

Tags: antlr4

(This came up in [Expression parsing with ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829231/java-expression-parsing-with-antlr))

Using the  [Java8Parser from the ANTLR grammars repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java8).

If I try to parse `return a.b.c();` using the `returnStatement` parser rule, I get an error on the `(` and `)`, though it's clearly a valid return statement.

[image: parse tree for return a.b.c();]

If, however, I just wrap it in braces (`{return a.b.c();}`) and use the `block` rule as the start rule, everything parses just fine:

[image: parse tree for {return a.b.c();}]

My best guess is that ANTLR needs the extra character of lookahead to manage this, but that just doesn't "seem right".

Can anyone explain why the first fails, and the second succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

Odd, I'd expect ANTLR to backtrack from ALT 2 and match ALT 3. Could very well be a bug.

If I swap ALT 2 and ALT 3:

```
methodInvocation_lfno_primary
    :   methodName '(' argumentList? ')'
    |   typeName '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'       // ALT 2
    |   expressionName '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')' // ALT 3
    |   'super' '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'
    |   typeName '.' 'super' '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'
    ;
```

to get this:

```
methodInvocation_lfno_primary
    :   methodName '(' argumentList? ')'
    |   expressionName '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'
    |   typeName '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'
    |   'super' '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'
    |   typeName '.' 'super' '.' typeArguments? Identifier '(' argumentList? ')'
    ;
```

it gets properly parsed:

[image]

(no idea if that causes something else to break though...).

Comment: Agreed, I expected the backtrack on the failure.  (which it seems to have done once wrapped in `{` and `}`).  I'm reluctant to call "bug", but it sure seems "buggy" :).  I'll have a dig into `typeName` and `expressionName` as those two alternatives are quite similar.  I can see where looking at the "right" one first "fixes" things, but a failure on the earlier alt should have tried the next alt.  (Should I move this to a discussion on Github?)

Comment: For C#, the parser parses "return a.b.c();" without error from `returnStatement`, recognizing the entire string. But, for Java, it does fail! `line 1:12 mismatched input '(' expecting '.'`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd open an issue/discussion on Github.